# nodemon as dev dependency in Docker container unexpectedly works also after npm ci

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I have a node/express/typescript application with nodemon hot reload. Nodemon is a dev dependency in my package.json.

The script `npm run dev` runs `npx nodemon src/app.ts` and it works after `RUN npm install` - good, this is expected.

What I don't understand, and would appreciate an explanation of, is - why it also does work when I install packages in the container via `RUN npm ci`. I would expect `npm ci` to only install production dependencies, in which case nodemon shouldn't even get installed. Still, it reacts to code changes.

When I `docker exec -it` into the container, `nodemon` clearly sits there among `node_modules`.

I have regenerated `package-lock.json` - it still has nodemon listed among dev dependencies.

Can anyone explain what is happening to me please?

My cycle is `docker-compose up --build` and `docker-compose down -v` (to make sure I tear down the volumes used for persistency). I also explicitly pruned all the volumes and images.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS base

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./package*.json .
COPY ./tsconfig.json .
RUN npm ci 

COPY . .

ENV PORT=3131
EXPOSE ${PORT}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: .
      target: base
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - api_net  
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3131:3131
      - 9229:9229
    env_file: ./.env
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - redis
    command: npm run dev  # <-     "dev": "npx nodemon src/app.ts",
# [... and other services]
```

Comment: Since you overwrite absolutely everything in your image with `volumes:`, changes in the Dockerfile have no effect.  In particular, you're telling Docker the `node_modules` directory contains important data that must not be automatically modified, and so a previous build's `node_modules` directory will get used even if you change the Dockerfile to `RUN npm ci`.  I might not use Docker with this sort of setup, ignoring the image system entirely; plain Node will be easier to manage.

Comment: You can run `npm ci --production` or `NODE_ENV=production npm ci` to not install devDependencies.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't really get the phrase _so a previous build's node_modules directory_ My understanding is that this directory should be torn down along with the volume when I prune the volumes and then node_modules are installed afresh. I am isolating node_modules so that the local OS doesn't leak binaries into container and vice versa.

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up --build`, change the Dockerfile or `package.json`, and run `docker-compose up --build` again, you will get the previous build's `node_modules` directory from the anonymous volume.

Comment: @DavidMaze Before I wrote my post I verified my findings, I made sure to tear down and erase all the volumes, named and unnamed, the result of `docker volume ls` was just an empty list, same with images - I erased everything except mongo, redis. My question is - what does "previous" mean? What is the point of removing volumes then?

Comment: this setup is good for development and here you are not creating an independent container. you compose file maps your development directory into the container thus it does not make use of the fresh npm install in it

Answer (score 0):

You are first doing a clean install and then copying everything from your workspace into the container.

working with nodejs, it is always best to have a `.dockerignore` file and have at least `**/node_modules` line in it

Also, compose file seems to shadow your container's app folder with the host's workspace. you may also want to check that.